# How to get library: OpenGL 3.1 and GLUT 3 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: opengl, ubuntu-12.04, glut

I'm taking a class in OpenGL. Everything must be compiled and run on a machine that has the OpenGL 3.1 and GLUT 3 library, so I need to make sure that is what I have.

I have a fresh copy of Ubuntu 12.04 installed so nothing extra outside of the basic installation.

Any help with setting me up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you wrote that you're taking an OpenGL course, I'll assume that you need the development files. Then try simply this:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

The OpenGL development files should be installed as a dependency of GLUT (the corresponding (virtual) package is `gl-dev` and one possible package is `libgl1-mesa-dev`).

Regarding the version of OpenGL this will get you, it will depend on both your hardware and the software drivers installed on your machine. Use `glxinfo` (from the `mesa-utils` package) to find out: the supported version should be in the OpenGL version string.

Comment: Fantastic, I can open the demo file my Prof sent out.

Many thanks!

It would seem I have gl version 1.3, so you say this is driver related, so a driver update would change this?